# Pointer sensitive Components in scrollable Container

Tags: codenameone

Apparently the `com.codename1.ui.Container.getComponentAt(int, int)` method decides which Component handles pointer events.

What would be required to create a scrollable list using a `com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` `Container` filled with arbitrary components - amongst those buttons and other active controls - which is still draggable/scrollable?

I'm thinking about creating a `Container` descendant which overrides `com.codename1.ui.Container.getComponentAt(int, int)` always returning its instance and handling all pointer events while also passing those to its child components. But I wonder whether this would be such a good idea. It's probably an adventurous untertaking, what do You think?

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be problematic in terms of usage since it would be hard for you to distinguish drag from scroll.

That's why we have `isDragAndDropOperation` which allows you to indicate if a specific area within the component is a "grabbable" and you can give that area a specific appearance to communicate that to the user.

Comment: When I set the container instances `focusable` attribute to true I can scroll the list even when pointing and dragging a button, for example. But then the button does not fire. By default I cannot scroll the container when dragging the button. What I want is arbitrary components in a list and have everything working at it is supposed to. But apparently this is difficult. Or is there a solution I have missed?

Comment: Some events are only sent to the focus component in Codename One which is probably why you aren't getting them. This is important in terms of performance otherwise all components would have to deal with a lot of information... You can accomplish this by overriding methods in Form which gets all of the calls.